# How do I end a pipe?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, pipe

I have trouble using `ffprobe` from node.js. I need the audio lengths MP3 files. There is an npm package, `get-audio-duration` for this.

The package calls `ffprobe` through an `execa` command. It works well for .flac files both when when using a filename and a stream. However for .mp3 files it fails for streams.

I suspected some problems with `execa` so I checked from the command line (on Windows 10):

```
type file.mp3 | ffprobe -
```

(Where I left out the parameters to `ffprobe` for clarity.)

This kind of works, but says `duration=N/A`.

It looks to me like `ffprobe` didn't get the info that the input is finished. Or, it dint care about it. (There is a 4 year old bug report about this on the `ffmpeg` issue site which was closed for no obvious reason.)

Is it possible to somehow tell `ffprobe` that the pipe has ended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a matter of noticing that the pipe has ended.

ffprobe uses a different way of determining the file size than is allowed by piping stdout to stdin

See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4358

Comment: Thanks, yes I've seen that issue. And that it is closed for some reason I don't understand. It looks like a simple bug to fix.

Comment: It may indeed be simple; but simple or not, it takes someone to do it and submit the patch. It seemingly hasn't bothered anyone enough for that to happen (yet).